# Camera/object shake while following path

Tags: constraints, path

Hi everyone and please forgive me for my bad English :p

I have a problem on my project when I add a path or a NURBS Curve. Indeed I want both an object and my camera following the path (a cockpit in space).

When I do all the steps and animate the path and press space, the object and camera both follow correctly the path but they are shaking.

I tried literally every options on the curve but nothing work.

I tried the exact same thing on a fresh new project with nothing on it and it works perfectly (Add camera and path, add Following path on camera and animate it.) No shakes and the camera follows the path.

[image: Here is the camera following the path, the orange square is shaking around the yellow square during the movement.]

It does the same effect on the object (the cockpit) it shake it during the movement.

Do you have any ideas of what it may be? I'm open to more questions and pictures!

Thank you a lot!

EDIT: this information was placed in an answer rather than as an update to the question.

So, I delete everything except the cockpit the camera and the curve. I noticed that when I scale up the cockpit to a normal size, there is no more shaking.

I also add a new curve and a new camera without touching the scale or anything except binding them together, there is still the shake.

Here's a link to my blender file: https://we.tl/t-HXczRld3n8

Comment: Maybe try to increase the curve resolution? If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: pls provide blend file (you can delete everything except the curves for the cam + object/cam, so that we can reproduce your behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not missing something else, the shaking is due to your cameras' *Clip End* values having been set to absurdly high numbers, as shown in the screenshot below. Like any other 3D program, Blender's spatial calculations cannot be infinitely precise so they must be performed within a reasonable range. That's what *Clip Start* and *Clip End* numbers control, and when they are too far apart from each other, you will start seeing all kinds of issues from shading flickers to shaking geometries. In your file, when I set these to `10` and `10.000`, respectively, shaking stopped, as an example. You should change these to something appropriate to your project.

Do be aware that you need to set these numbers for both your viewport in the <kbd>N</kbd> *> View* panel, and for all your distinct *Camera* objects individually in their *Properties > Camera Object Data* panel.

[image]

You also have objects with very high *Scale* values in your file. This can, too, cause problems down the line. In most cases, once you're happy with the dimensions of an object, you should apply its scale so it reads `Scale X:1, Y:1, Z:1` in the *View > Item > Transform* tab. You can do this either from the *Object > Apply* menu, or pressing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and choosing "*Scale*".

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for this very useful answer, I didn’t know that putting max value on clipping would cause me trouble ! Same for objects sizes.

Comment: @JulienCalix You're welcome. I had done the exact same mistake when I first started learning Blender, so I sympathize. If this was indeed the answer to your problem, you should "accept" it as a solution (the big tick near the upvote button).